# Save image proportion (height) when width of ImageView fill width of parent at LaunchScreen

Tags: ios, swift, screen, launch, xcode-storyboard

I want to make Launchcreen.storyboard for my SwiftUI project, and need to resize image for all devices, that width of image = width of screen with saving image proportion. When i fix size on iPhone SE - i have this problem on iPad:

[image]

And when i fix height on iPad, i have problem on iPhones:

[image]

How can i do it, if i can't change height programmatically in viewDidLoad() (because this is LaunchScreen)?

Comment: what is your ImageView contentMode? you need to set it .scaleAspectFit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your image content mode is `.aspectFit`, then you would have to apply the following constraints:

- Enter the width and height on the image size inspector so you can
  control + drag from the image to set the aspect ratio
- Leading and Trailing -> Pinned To Safe Area ( = 0 ) ( so it fits the whole width)
- Aligned in Center Y ( because you won't always occupy the full height
  necessarily )
- Top and Bottom -> Pinned To Safe Area ( >= 0 ) ( so it
  does not go off the screen)